# Regex ignore redundant braces

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I am building a lex program that will analyze something like the following...

```
function myFunc {
    if a = b {
        print "Cool"
    }
}
```

Is it possible, specifically using flex, to create a regex that will single out everything in the first { }

so i will get

```
{ if a = b { print "Cool" } }
```

instead of

```
{ if a = b { print "Cool" }
```

Currently in my flex file i have this regex
    {[^\0]*}

Comment: seems matching curly braces should be something what `bison` do, but not `flex`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem with what you are trying to do is that RegEx is greedy by default (could do some tricks to change that, but you'll still have problems), and you will match more than intended if you run this on a file with multiple functions in it. The reason is that most programming languages are [Type 1 grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy#Type-1_grammars) in the Chomsky hierarchy, or context-sensitive grammars, and RegEx is a Type 2 (context-free) grammar. It is fundamentally impossible to directly parse the former using the later without a LOT of work. The full explanation for that is ... long. But it boils down to in context sensitive grammars the meaning of a given element can change depending on where you are in the input, while in a context-free grammar every element has exactly one meaning. In your case, you don't want to match any ole' `}`, you want to match the corresponding `}` to an open `{`, which involves counting the number of `{` and `}` you have seen so far.

If you really want to do code parsing without having to re-invent the wheel, the plow, fire, steel, and all the way up to electricity, I would recommend that you go check out [AnTLR](https://github.com/antlr) over on GitHub. AnTLR will allow you to create a grammar (if one does not already exist) for the language you are trying to parse and provide the parsed source code to you in the form of a [Parse Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parse_tree). Parse trees are very, very easy to use and AnTLR has grammars already for almost every language imaginable, and [plugins for several languages](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/targets.md).

Other than that, both the online regex tester I used and Notepad++ with your sample code matched everything. You could try the RegEx `{.*}` which also matches everything.